# Ubuntu public IP

Tags: networking, server, 20.04

I'm from Romania and I setup an Ubuntu server and it is on a private IP address **"192.168.x.x"**.
I contacted my Internet Service Provider **(ISP)** and he told me

> this Dedicated ipv4 is not allocated for individuals, only for legal entities

What can I do? How can I make my Ubuntu server public?
Why do I need a public IP?

I want to create a node on my Pterodactyl server an public node to create Public servers.

Comment: You have to rent a VPS server from a cloud provider. Search on the Internet. Some providers like Oracle will give away some very small servers for free. However, I don't know the software in your Question and its system requirements and whether it can run on a VPS. As an alternate solution, you can connect your "local" server to a "public" VPS using a VPN software like _WireGuard_.

Comment: i have some VPS from Microsoft Azure is it good ?

Comment: If you connect another computer to the same network as your Ubuntu server and Google **what is my IP address** then you should get your public IP address. This address may change anytime.

Comment: i add my public ip in to a new ubuntu server in proxmox but when i try **ping google.com** i got error or **apt update**

Comment: Does your ISP give you IPv6?

Comment: i can give a mail to my ISP to check

Comment: How is our server connected to the Internet? Do you have a router in your home that allows connection to many computers? Do you own the router, or is it from the ISP? Can you change the settings in the router and set up port forwarding? Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1500128/edit) and add all these information.

Answer (score 3):

*Prelude: For your purpose you need to know your public IPv4 address, which may not be static.*

It seems like your problem stems from a serious misunderstanding of how the internet works. The [IP range](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) 192.168.x.x/16 is a private IPv4 range, which means that it is only valid/routed on your private network/**LAN**(**L**ocal **A**rea **N**etwork).

This leads to the next part of the question:

> Why do I need a public IP?

You need a public (IPv4) address for your server to be *reachable* from the internet. The above mentioned *private ranges*

```
10.0.0.0    – 10.255.255.255
172.16.0.0  – 172.31.255.255
192.168.0.0 – 192.168.255.255
```

are **not reachable** from the internet. So the answer from your ISP is quite strange. They should have told you that the IP you're using is not intended to be public.

> How can I make my Ubuntu server public?

To make your server reachable from the internet, you would need to refer to a *public IP address*, which is not always *static*, but can be set dynamically by your internet provider - not all internet providers provide you a **static IPv4 address**. Often you are behind some kind of [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation).

You always have a *public IP* address when connecting to the internet, but not always a *static IPv4* address. If your IP address is not *static*, but rather assigned *dynamically*, you can also use a dynamic DNS service (like [DynDNS](https://account.dyn.com) or others) which provides you a DNS entry and updates your IPv4 address every time the daemon updates it.

Comment: The core of the answer is in the final two paragraphs. Consider moving those up to the top.

Comment: Note that some ISPs might hand a private IP (so not routable after all) to your home router through a NAT (common in mobile 4G/5G based links for home subscribers) so in that case only an established connection from within your server e.g after handshake or a tunnel e.g. VPN pipe might accept packets from the outside world … A dynamic DNS provider with relay (if they offer it) through an established connection initiated from your server might be an option.

Comment: I have a public ip, but is dynamic if someone can really help me contact me on discord ".pasat" this is my discord

Comment: @Raffa is right. some ISPs (particularly in East European countries) use NAT and thus non-routable IP addresses. I have seen a similar question before, where it was not possible to access the home network from outside.